# Can't serialize object type Clob in Mulesoft

Tags: clob, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm trying to receive information from a table with a Clob type attribute a this is what the object appears like in the payload:

```
TypedValue[value: 'org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider@1c11df37', dataType: 'SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='text/plain'}']
```

It's the BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE and BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE attributes being used in the following flow:

```xml
    <flow name="SYS_TBGQUEUEMigrationFlow" doc:id="1302cd81-6b21-424b-9bb8-b097d2ab0c3a" >
        <db:select doc:name="Select SYS_TBGQUEUE from Oracle DB" doc:id="c7b33299-b772-4134-abdd-c7dcb3ad630a" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB" >
            <db:sql >SELECT * FROM SYS_TBGQUEUE</db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <batch:job jobName="sysLogicBatch_Job" doc:id="08898cbe-62c5-4028-9f4f-dc8be9e6d0d9" >
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="836a7495-415c-4d5f-945a-03f1f2358cd8" >
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="0425e88e-5e07-4f04-9016-872ccef025bd" streaming="true">
                        <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="a2af7287-961e-4c1e-bd13-993d00e75370">
                            <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Insert into SYS_TBGQUEUE" doc:id="692971ea-d05c-430b-9ae4-3fe8b6d439dc" config-ref="Database_Config">
                                <db:sql>{call InsertIntoBgQueue (:BGQUEUE_CODE, :BGQUEUETYPE_CODE, :IDENTITY_CODE, :BGQUEUE_DATE_INSERT, :BGQUEUE_LOCK_WORKER_ID, 
:BGQUEUE_EXEC_START_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_EXPIRE_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_RETRIES, 
:BGQUEUE_EXEC_HEARTBEAT_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_END_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_ENUM, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE, :BGQUEUE_STATUS)}</db:sql>
                                <db:input-parameters><![CDATA[#[{
    BGQUEUE_CODE                : payload.bgqueue_code,
    BGQUEUETYPE_CODE            : payload.bgqueuetype_code,
    IDENTITY_CODE               : payload.identity_code,
    BGQUEUE_DATE_INSERT : payload.bgqueue_date_insert,
    BGQUEUE_LOCK_WORKER_ID      : payload.bgqueue_lock_worker_id,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_START_DATE         : payload.bgqueue_exec_start_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_EXPIRE_DATE            : payload.bgqueue_exec_expire_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE          : payload.bgqueue_exec_value as String,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_RETRIES        : payload.bgqueue_exec_retries,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_HEARTBEAT_DATE : payload.bgqueue_exec_heartbeat_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_END_DATE       : payload.bgqueue_exec_end_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_ENUM    : payload.bgqueue_exec_status_enum,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE   : payload.bgqueue_exec_status_value as String,
    BGQUEUE_STATUS              : payload.bgqueue_status
    }]]]></db:input-parameters>
                            </db:stored-procedure>
                        </foreach>
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a79350d8-65e9-44ac-a966-8a27036a5477" message="SYS_TBGQUEUE finished data migration." />
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
    </flow>
```

This is the error message:

```
Message               : Could not dispatch records to batch queue BSQ-sysLogicBatch_Job-ab0fcad0-7b15-11ea-9403-3e6fc91c389b due to Serialization Exception
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
Element               : SYS_TBGQUEUEMigrationFlow/processors/1 @ DatabaseConnectorPOC:sysLogic.xml:114
Element XML           : <batch:job jobName="sysLogicBatch_Job" doc:id="08898cbe-62c5-4028-9f4f-dc8be9e6d0d9">
<batch:process-records>
<batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="836a7495-415c-4d5f-945a-03f1f2358cd8">
<batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="0425e88e-5e07-4f04-9016-872ccef025bd" streaming="true">
<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="a2af7287-961e-4c1e-bd13-993d00e75370">
<db:stored-procedure doc:name="Insert into SYS_TBGQUEUE" doc:id="692971ea-d05c-430b-9ae4-3fe8b6d439dc" config-ref="Database_Config">
<db:sql>{call InsertIntoBgQueue (:BGQUEUE_CODE, :BGQUEUETYPE_CODE, :IDENTITY_CODE, :BGQUEUE_DATE_INSERT, :BGQUEUE_LOCK_WORKER_ID,:BGQUEUE_EXEC_START_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_EXPIRE_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_RETRIES, 
:BGQUEUE_EXEC_HEARTBEAT_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_END_DATE, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_ENUM, :BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE, :BGQUEUE_STATUS)}</db:sql>
<db:input-parameters>#[output application/java
---
{
    BGQUEUE_CODE                : payload.bgqueue_code,
    BGQUEUETYPE_CODE            : payload.bgqueuetype_code,
    IDENTITY_CODE               : payload.identity_code,
    BGQUEUE_DATE_INSERT : payload.bgqueue_date_insert,
    BGQUEUE_LOCK_WORKER_ID      : payload.bgqueue_lock_worker_id,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_START_DATE         : payload.bgqueue_exec_start_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_EXPIRE_DATE            : payload.bgqueue_exec_expire_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE          : payload.bgqueue_exec_value,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_RETRIES        : payload.bgqueue_exec_retries,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_HEARTBEAT_DATE : payload.bgqueue_exec_heartbeat_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_END_DATE       : payload.bgqueue_exec_end_date,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_ENUM    : payload.bgqueue_exec_status_enum,
    BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE   : payload.bgqueue_exec_status_value,
    BGQUEUE_STATUS              : payload.bgqueue_status
    }]</db:input-parameters>
</db:stored-procedure>
</foreach>
</batch:aggregator>
</batch:step>
</batch:process-records>
<batch:on-complete>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a79350d8-65e9-44ac-a966-8a27036a5477" message="SYS_TBGQUEUE finished data migration."></logger>
</batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Does anyone know how I can convert it into a String?
Thank you!

Comment: That's not an error. It appears to be the description of the payload. Please post the complete error message.

Comment: My bad, I've updated the post! Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be that it is not possible to serialize the Clob to load the Batch Job queue.

You may need to convert the Clob into String before entering the Batch Job with a transform like this:

```
( payload map {
BGQUEUE_CODE                : payload.bgqueue_code,
BGQUEUETYPE_CODE            : payload.bgqueuetype_code,
IDENTITY_CODE               : payload.identity_code,
BGQUEUE_DATE_INSERT : payload.bgqueue_date_insert,
BGQUEUE_LOCK_WORKER_ID      : payload.bgqueue_lock_worker_id,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_START_DATE         : payload.bgqueue_exec_start_date,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_EXPIRE_DATE            : payload.bgqueue_exec_expire_date,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_VALUE          : (payload.bgqueue_exec_value as String) default "",
BGQUEUE_EXEC_RETRIES        : payload.bgqueue_exec_retries,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_HEARTBEAT_DATE : payload.bgqueue_exec_heartbeat_date,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_END_DATE       : payload.bgqueue_exec_end_date,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_ENUM    : payload.bgqueue_exec_status_enum,
BGQUEUE_EXEC_STATUS_VALUE   : (payload.bgqueue_exec_status_value as String) default "",
BGQUEUE_STATUS              : payload.bgqueue_status
} ) as Iterator
```

The "as Iterator" is just an optimization that can be removed if you see there is a bug related to that (like a DB session error)

Then in db:input-parameters you will need to put just "payload" as the names will already match with the ones you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did as you suggested but got this error: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
I also checked the content of the payload and the Clob objects had the default value "" instead of their original value.

Do you have any idea of how I could fix this?

Comment: That error conversion error looks to be happening when the JDBC driver is converting the params to the java.sql (JDBC interfaz) ones. You will need to identify which is the param that is failing and cast it to the right "Type" (java class). If it's an output param, maybe you need to specify also the custom type on the output parameters table. Maybe with a mocked store procedure I can play and see what is happening, but support on this case may act faster.